# How to catch 1 tap with 3 fingers (NSEvent) on a custom NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mousedown, nsevent

I have to following code to catch `mouseDown`s on my custom `NSView` but I think this only catches how many taps (using the `clickCount`), not how many fingers were used to tap:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas{
    if(trackingArea != nil) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }
    int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways);
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                 options:opts
                                                   owner:self
                                                userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"%li",theEvent.clickCount);
    if ([theEvent clickCount] == 3){
        NSLog(@"3");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"normal");
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to catch 1 tap with 3 fingers on my custom NSView? I'd like to reproduce something like the Finder.app option, where you tap with 3 fingers on a file and a QuickLook panel shows up.
Thanks!

Comment: No-repro here. More details are probably needed.

Comment: As per my experience with other language, using timers ( time based loops ) is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in the mouseUp: method (instead of mouseDown:). Also, you don't have to set up a tracking area to receive mouseUp: or mouseDown: events.

Answer (score -1):

**Click Events**

////////////////////

"You will get the event "click count" from the method "[theEvent clickCount]", if you are clicking fast enough in NSView.

Try logging the click count in mouseDown

NSLog(@"%d",[theEvent clickCount]); & try clicking little faster."

///////////////////

**Touch Events**

//////////////////

In OS X >= 10.6, you can try overriding these touch event gestures

- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEndedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelledWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event;

&

add

[self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES]; in init

/////////////////

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: Yes, but what I'm trying to do is to catch triple taps (3 fingers at the same time, not 1-2-3 taps).